# Python keras - word embeddings

Tags: python, anaconda, keras, word2vec, word-embedding

I have the following question:

I am using the `anaconda` `python`.
Within the datasets of keras there is a dataset that deals with [movie review sentiment classification](http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/), or `imdb`.

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data()
```

According to the documentation the dataset is now ready to be used.
Basically the words have been replaced by integers that indicate the ordered frequency of each word in the data set. The sentences in each revision are therefore composed of a sequence of integers.
Here's the question, I'd like to know a way to "convert" a new dataset to this input pattern for keras.

Sorry for the errors, I'm new to python and I'm trying to study ml.

I tried doing this through `word2vec` but I do not know if I'm on the right path:

```
word2vec.train_on_corpus(
    open('my-corpus.txt').read(),
    num_embedding_dimensions=500
)
```

The example was with a text, however I have an architecture where each the name of each folder is the label and inside each folder I have the txt documents.

Another way I "got" was by using `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",   
                         tokenizer = None,    
                         preprocessor = None, 
                         stop_words = None,   
                         max_features = 5000) 

train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)
train_data_features = train_data_features.toarray()
```

Do you have other alternatives that I can use? The current approach is this way really?
But I still have no idea how to bind a text vector to a label

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do in keras. Do you want word vectors for the imdb data? Then probably you should look at [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format). Kindly elaborate your question so that I can answer properly.

Comment: I would like to transform the sentence context into integer vectors corresponding to the frequency of each word

Comment: I got it using the countVetorizer plus I'm in doubt if it's the best approach `from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer` `train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)`
`train_data_features = train_data_features.toarray()`

Comment: I don't know the best approach for frequency counting. I usually do that manually by reading the text in a python loop and creating a word-frequency dictionary. Your method using `sklearn` seems better than mine.